# Web part error - (401) Unauthorized

Tags: web-part, xslt

I have a little program that queries a web service, transforms the results using XSLT and displays them in a jQuery control.  When I move the code into a web part it and deploy it, however I'm getting the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

This is the code that's loading my XSLT file, which is where I suspect the problem is:

```
XPathDocument xPathDoc;
XsltArgumentList args;

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  xPathDoc = QueryRunner.GetQueryResults();
  args = QueryRunner.GetColumnsToShow();
}

public static XPathDocument GetQueryResults()
{
  OpacAccess.OpacAccess proxy = new OpacAccess.OpacAccess();

  string result = string.Empty;

  try
  {
     result = proxy.query("CompanyName", "username", "password", 
         ReadingList=\"London\"", 1000);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }

  // Store the xml of the result
  XPathDocument xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(result));

  return xPathDoc;
}   

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();

  // Load the xslt file and perform the transformation
  xslt.Load("http://rginfonet/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/Liberty.xslt");
  xslt.Transform(xPathDoc, args, output, null);
  output.Flush();
}
```

Here's my stack trace if it's at all helpful to anyone:

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +5375213
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +69
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) +3929371
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +54
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +74
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +70
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +108
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +186
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +208
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +217
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +20
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Compiler.LoadDocument(XmlTextReaderImpl reader) +85
   System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load(String url, XmlResolver resolver) +100
   System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load(String url) +25
   LibertyControl.ResultsGrid.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +66

[WebPartException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +140
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part) +63
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderZoneCell(HtmlTextWriter output, Boolean bMoreParts, WebPart part) +144
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderWebParts(HtmlTextWriter output, ArrayList webParts) +495
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +902
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +163
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266

Please let me know if you can lend some insight to what's causing this.  Thanks!

Comment: how do you query the web service ? from the code behind ? What are the authentication mechanism of the web service ?

Comment: Yes, I'm querying from the code-behind.  I'm using a web reference to query the service.  I will include the code for the GetQueryResults method in my original question so you can see. I'm not doing any fancy authentication.

Comment: "I'm not doing any fancy authentication", but are doing authentication ?

Comment: and also, how did you create the service reference ? WCF or legacy web reference ?

Comment: Did you unit test it without any sharepoint? Like just from command line?

Comment: @Steve - just the authentication as required by the web service (username and password).  I have tested it outside of sharepoint and it worked fine.  Right-click service references -> add service reference -> Advanced... -> Add Web Reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the stack trace, I think the web service call is not the problem. This line is probably causing the exception :

```
xslt.Load("http://rginfonet/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/Liberty.xslt");
```

In fact, you are facing a douple-hop scenario. Your user connects to SP, where the webparts also try to connect to SP (even if it's local).

Try to change the `xslt.Load` method to not an Uri, but a stream :

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
  var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
  var styleFile = web.GetFile("Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/Liberty.xslt");
  using(var stream = styleFile.OpenBinaryStream())
  {
    using(var xr = XmlReader.CreateDefault(stream))
    {
      // Load the xslt file and perform the transformation
      xslt.Load(xr);
      xslt.Transform(xPathDoc, args, output, null);
      }
  }
  output.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I had to tweak the code a bit, but I got this to work.  Thanks!  Now, I just need to get my jQuery working.